# using outputcache increase db connection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Glimpse to track sql statistics on my pages.

Recently I begin to use `outputcache` on several of my actions. however glimpse show that the number of db queries on the page that using `outputcache` increase to 7 which normally and without `outputcache` is 2 queries.

Here is one of my actions:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchString, int? page)
```

Here are the queries:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = 'MEF.DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration' /* @p__linq__0 */
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [c].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [c]

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = 'MEF.DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration' /* @p__linq__0 */

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
    [Project1].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [Project1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
        [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
        [Extent1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = 'MEF.DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration' /* @p__linq__0 */
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
    [Project1].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [Project1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
        [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
        [Extent1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = 'MEF.DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration' /* @p__linq__0 */
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC

SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Animes] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[EnglishName] AS [EnglishName], 
    [Extent1].[PersianName] AS [PersianName]
    FROM [dbo].[Animes] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[EnglishName] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Am i missing something? why number of db queries increase using `outputcache`?